# MySQL inner join to update an existing table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table called `empty` as follows which only has the paperkey value and everything else is empty.

```
author | year | conference | paperkey
                               1234
```

And I have another table called `base` as follows:

```
author | year | conference | paperkey
Andrew   1999     KDD           1234
```

I want to insert the value retrieved in table `base` to table `empty`.

I tried to query as follows but it did not work. How can I modify this query to get the right result?

```
insert into empty (author, year, conference)
select T1.author, T1.year, T1.conference
from base as T1
inner join empty as T2 on T1.paperkey=T2.paperkey;
```

Comment: You want to update existing records, not insert new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update existing records, not insert new ones.

```
update empty T2
join base T1 on T1.paperkey = T2.paperkey
set T2.author = T1.author,
    T2.year = T1.year,
    T2.conference = T1.conference
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to update `empty` based on `paperkey`

```
update empty e
join base b on b.paperkey = e.paperkey
set 
e.author = b.author,
e.year = b.year,
e.conference = b.conference
```